# Angular + Jquery, ангулар перестает работать после того как я использую load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
    angular.module("myApp",[])
    .controller("firstCtrl",function ($scope) {
    $scope.startTest = function(){
        $("#testJquery").load("/pickFavoriteActors.html");
    }
    $scope.pickGenresButton = function(){
            console.log("this works?");
            pickYourGenre($('#slider-vertical').slider("option", "value"),$('#slider-vertical2').slider("option", "value"),
                $('#slider-vertical3').slider("option", "value"),
                $('#slider-vertical4').slider("option", "value"),
```

$('#slider-vertical5').slider("option", "value"));
    }

Условно говоря startTest присвоено кнопке, и когда кнопку нажимают загружается следующая страница, но ней абсолютно перестает работать angular. Все в {{}} выглядит как обычный текст, а кнопки не реагируют на нажатия

Проблема в том что , страницы отдельно друг от друга работают нормально, но если я пытаюсь использовать load, angular полностью перестает работать.
Страница при использовании load : http://prntscr.com/m70sz7
Страница если на нее просто зайти: http://prntscr.com/m70ujo

Comment: заюзайте стандартный http модуль  ангулара $http будет как то так  $htttp.get('/pickFavoriteActors.html').then(html => $("#testJquery").html = html)

Comment: @Санитариум Попробывал, он ругался на то что $http не определен добавил его в контролер, controller("firstCtrl",function ($scope,$http)
Ругаться перестал, но при нажатии на кнопку не происходит вообще нечего

Comment: Для того, что бы заработало, надо что бы angularjs скомпилировал html. Вы же просто загружаете html. Попробуйте использовать директиву для этого.